# Match SQL Columns based on user input

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

This is my first post on this forum and i surely hope to get some help from gurus :)

What i am trying to achieve is that there are 7 columns in my db table. one is primary key and rest 6 are integer columns. Now my application will allow user to input 6 values. I want to compare 6 values entered by user to those 6 integer columns and if in any row 3 or more columns match user's input Primary key of that table is returned..

I have tried using queries, cursor, nested loops and i am still unable to achieve my results..

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

UPDATED

DB Table Structure.. I am inputting `2,3,7,11,45,65`. Number of returned rows should be 5. eg..

```
UID A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6
-----------------------
1   2  3  4  5  6  7
2   2  3  4  55 56 57
3   65 11 45 66 67 68
4   45 7  11 99 98 97
5   7  7  7  7  7  7
6   7  7  7  7  7  7
7   8  8  8  8  8  8
8   8  8  8  8  8  8
9   45 45 0  3  1  2
10  65 7  4  0  0  0
```

IDs returned should be `1,3,4,9,10`

Comment: how are you generating the primary key?

Comment: Important question: Are you trying to match the inputs to corresponding columns (combination lock) or can any input match any column? In other words, does 1,2,3,4,5,6 match 6,5,4,7,7,7 three times or zero times?  

Also, are duplicate numbers allowed or is this more like a Keno problem?

Comment: Any input could match any column in the db..

Comment: You are only inputting 5 numbers.  Did you miss one?  It will help with understanding your responses to see all the data.  Also, I assume you don't want to match multiple hits.  By this I mean, if the user inputs 7 once in his 6 numbers, you only want to match once against UID 5 and 6, not 6 times, correct?  What if the user enters 2,2,2,2,2,2?  Do you only want to match against any individual 2 once, so rows 1 and 2 would not be successes?

Comment: Hi nycdan.. no you are taking it wrong.. the db table is given above.. suppose i send 2,3,45,7,11,65 as 6 values in my query.. now if you see the db table then it should return uid 1,3,4,9,10.. reason? they all have atleast 3 of the inputted numbers. 777777 row shouldn't be fetched.. coz it contains only one number 7 6 times not 3 different columns.. did you get it?

Comment: yes.  But you left the 11 out of your data entry list above, hence my question.

Answer (score 2):

Dummy data (from MSDN PIVOT example)

```
CREATE TABLE Mytable (PK int, col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int, col5 int, col6 int)
GO
INSERT INTO Mytable VALUES (1, 1,4,3,5,4,4)
INSERT INTO Mytable VALUES (2, 2,4,1,5,5,5)
INSERT INTO Mytable VALUES (3, 3,4,3,5,4,4)
INSERT INTO Mytable VALUES (4, 4,4,2,5,5,4)
INSERT INTO Mytable VALUES (5, 5,5,1,5,5,5)
GO
```

Input data

```
DECLARE @MyInput TABLE (InputValue int)
INSERT @MyInput VALUES (2)
INSERT @MyInput VALUES (4)
INSERT @MyInput VALUES (5)
```

UNPIVOT source column data into rows. Now we can JOIN and aggregate to find where we have 3 matches without massive OR clauses

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    myTable MT2 --effectively PIVOT back to get original rows
    JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        PK
    FROM --7 columns into 3, make column name a row identifier
        (SELECT PK, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 FROM myTable) MT
        UNPIVOT
        (colvalue FOR RowNumber IN (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)) cols
        JOIN   --match to user input, set based
        @MyInput MD ON cols.colvalue = MD.InputValue
    GROUP BY
        PK  --per original row
    HAVING 
        COUNT(DISTINCT MD.InputValue) >= 3
    ) foo ON MT2.PK = foo.PK
```

This works for sets 2, 4, 5 and 1, 4, 5

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through the values and add **1** to a variable for each column that meets the comparison criteria.

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @Accumulator int
DECLARE @Threshold int
DECLARE @ReturnValue int

DECLARE @PK int
DECLARE @Col1 int
DECLARE @Col2 int
DECLARE @Col3 int
DECLARE @Col4 int
DECLARE @Col5 int
DECLARE @Col6 int

DECLARE @UserInput1 int
DECLARE @UserInput2 int
DECLARE @UserInput3 int
DECLARE @UserInput4 int
DECLARE @UserInput5 int
DECLARE @UserInput6 int

-- Assuming you would set each @UserInputx above to a value input by the user...

SET @Accumulator = 0
SET @Threshold = 3
SET @ReturnValue = 0

SELECT
    @PK = PrimaryKey,
    @Col1 = Col1,
    @Col2 = Col2,
    @Col3 = Col3,
    @Col4 = Col4,
    @Col5 = Col5,
    @Col6 = Col6
FROM TheTable

IF @Col1 IN (@UserInput1, @UserInput2, @UserInput3, @UserInput4, @UserInput5, @UserInput6) 
    SET @Accumulator = @Accumulator + 1

IF @Col2 IN (@UserInput1, @UserInput2, @UserInput3, @UserInput4, @UserInput5, @UserInput6) 
    SET @Accumulator = @Accumulator + 1

IF @Col3 IN (@UserInput1, @UserInput2, @UserInput3, @UserInput4, @UserInput5, @UserInput6) 
    SET @Accumulator = @Accumulator + 1

IF @Col4 IN (@UserInput1, @UserInput2, @UserInput3, @UserInput4, @UserInput5, @UserInput6) 
    SET @Accumulator = @Accumulator + 1

IF @Col5 IN (@UserInput1, @UserInput2, @UserInput3, @UserInput4, @UserInput5, @UserInput6) 
    SET @Accumulator = @Accumulator + 1

IF @Col6 IN (@UserInput1, @UserInput2, @UserInput3, @UserInput4, @UserInput5, @UserInput6) 
    SET @Accumulator = @Accumulator + 1

IF @Accumulator >= 3
    SET @ReturnValue = @PK
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be easiest to implement

```
SELECT ID

from TABLE

WHERE 

CASE WHEN integerCol1 IN 
(@user1,@user2,@user3,@user4,@user5,@user6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN integerCol2 IN 
(@user1,@user2,@user3,@user4,@user5,@user6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN integerCol3 IN 
(@user1,@user2,@user3,@user4,@user5,@user6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN integerCol4 IN 
(@user1,@user2,@user3,@user4,@user5,@user6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN integerCol5 IN 
(@user1,@user2,@user3,@user4,@user5,@user6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN integerCol6 IN 
(@user1,@user2,@user3,@user4,@user5,@user6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END >=3
```

Comment: El Ronnoco, I tired using your sql query it returns wrong. it even returns the row which has same character in all 6 columns.. and it misses 2 columns which should be returned

Comment: @user587619 Ah yes, my mistake. It only cares if 3 of the columns have any of the user inputs. It does no checking if the three columns are unique... Hmmm....

Comment: @user587619 However I don't know why it would *not* return a row which should be returned?...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to write code, but you mentioned you tried a nested loop.  Now that I understand what you want to do, I can give you at least a nudge in a direction I think will work for you.

In your inner loop, you will grab the first list you want to compare your input to, then take the first of your inputs and compare it to each member of the list until you reach a match or the end.  Now the tricky part...since you don't want to match a second number of your input to the same member of the list twice (if you entered 2 7s for example) you should change the member you matched to to some illegal number.  If only positive numbers are allowed, change it to -1.  This ensure you won't match against it twice.

Now in our middle loop, work through the rest of your input numbers against that same list until you are done.  In order to determine a match, count the occurences of -1 (or whatever you use to indicate a match) in that list and you will have you success/failure indicator.

In your outer loop, go through each list the same way.

In very rough psuedo-code:

```
var x = set of all lists  
foreach (list l in x)  //go through each list
{  
 foreach (item i in inputlist)  //go through each item in your input
  {
    foreach (item j in l) //compare to each item in the current list
      {
         if (i = j) 
           {
              j = -1;  //set matched item to -1 to avoid rematching
              sum[l]++;
           }
      }
  }
}
```

when complete, any list where sum[l] >=3 is a match.

Comment: somewhat like your approach :)

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks everyone for responses but neither of it helped me :P

Nested loops to go through the dataset or gridview whatever suits you..

The way i turned it around was to concatenate a row's all columns values including some special character.. like if a row has 1 2 3 4 5 6 values.. it became [1][2][3][4][5][6] and then using the .Contains function compared the values if found use .Replace to exclude it from string making sure it is not counted when loop is incremented..

A classic approach.. but it was worth it!

Thanks guys :)